# in ARKit, how do you crop a video to the size of the anchor WITHOUT stretching to fill the frame?

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, video-player

I have an AR app on iOS with everything working fine for videos popping up to fill the detected anchor image, but with odd shaped anchors, like vertical oriented images, the video is always stretched to fill the space. I just want to crop, not stretch.

Here's what I have been doing, and it doesn't seem to work. I declared the following:

```
var player = AVPlayer()
var videoScene: SKScene!
var scaleMode: SKSceneScaleMode!
var videoNode: SKVideoNode!
```

Here's what plays the video when an anchor is detected. That's where I set the scaleMode to .aspectFill:

```
func setupVideoNode(){
    videoNode = SKVideoNode(avPlayer: player)

    let time = CMTime(value: vtime, timescale: 1)
    player.seek(to: time)
    
    player.play()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem, queue: nil) { (notification) in
        self.player.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
        self.player.play()

    }
    videoScene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 960, height: 720))

    scaleMode = .aspectFill

    videoNode.position = CGPoint(x: videoScene.size.width / 2, y: videoScene.size.height / 2)
    videoNode.yScale = -1.0
    videoScene.addChild(videoNode)
}
```

Here's what I have for the renderer, which calls setupVideoNode when it has found the anchor and related video file:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

    guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor,
          let name = imageAnchor.referenceImage.name,
          let fileUrlString = Bundle.main.path(forResource: getFileName(name: name), ofType: "mp4")
          else {return}

    url = fileUrlString
    
    let videoItem = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: fileUrlString))
    
    player.replaceCurrentItem(with: videoItem)
    setupVideoNode()

    // create a plan that has the same real world height and width as our detected image
    let plane = SCNPlane(width: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.width, height: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.height)
    // set the first materials content to be our video scene
    plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = videoScene
    // create a node out of the plane
    let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
    // since the created node will be vertical, rotate it along the x axis to have it be horizontal or parallel to our detected image
    planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -Float.pi / 2
    // finally add the plane node (which contains the video node) to the added node
    node.addChildNode(planeNode)
}
```

In the xcode documentation it describes SKSceneScaleMode.aspectFill this way:

"The scaling factor of each dimension is calculated and the larger of the two is chosen. Each axis of the scene is scaled by the same scaling factor. This guarantees that the entire area of the view is filled but may cause parts of the scene to be cropped."

That's what I want to do, but it's not working that way. It's still stretching the video to fill the frame. Any help would be greatly appreciated!